# how to exclude folder from redirect inside htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i have a website and it was working fine if i use `example.com` or `example.com/wp-admin`

but was not working if i use `www.example.com` or `www.example.com/wp-admin`

i redirected `example.com` to `www.example.com` and now neither `www.example.com/wp-admin` or `example.com/wp-admin` dont work. i get a blank page

here is what i got so far:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

any ideas on how to redirect everything but `www.example.com/wp-admin` 
??

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is the re-write rules?  It sounds like www.example.com never worked.... and now you are redirecting everything to www.example.com, so nothing works.  You might want to make sure your DNS / virtual host is set up properly... www can be set up to be different than non-www.

However, to answer yoru question, just add an additional condition.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```